# When i tried to run auth login api getting error : The current path, api/auth/login/, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When i tried to run api `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login/`, It gives me this error :

```
Using the URLconf defined in djangoproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    api/(?P<version>(v1|v2))/
    ^ ^users/$ [name='user-list']
    ^ ^users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-list']
    ^ ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='user-detail']
    ^ ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-detail']
    ^ ^$ [name='api-root']
    ^ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
    ^auth/

The current path, api/auth/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

Can anyone please check my urls.py and help me why i am getting this error ?

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path,include

from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from trialrisk.views import UserViewSet
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('api/(?P<version>(v1|v2))/', include('trialrisk.urls')),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url('^auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Because /auth/login is not under /api/.

Comment: thanks, so i should remove api/ from ths URL right ?